# Resolution of $\int_{1}^{e} \int_{0}^{y} 1/(x^2+y^2) \,dxdy$ step by step

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Can someone help me with this integral? I can not solve it, what am I missing? I used symbolab to get the answer that is pi/4, but I dont understand why.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the integral in polar coordinates? If not, do so immediately!

Comment: $\int_{1}^{e}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$ = $\int_{1}^{e} \frac{1}{y} \tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})_{x=0}^{x=y}dy$ = $\int_{1}^{e} \frac{\pi}{4y} dy$ = $\frac{\pi}{4} (\ln(y))_{y=1}^{y=e}$ = $\frac{\pi}{4}$